# Software (IDE) for web-automation

Tags: automation, ruby

I'm learning web-automation by myself, really like just using iTerm with Watir and SublimeText, BUT understood it's better to use some IDE software so I can see results of my test cases (for the record). 
 
What I know: 
- basics of Ruby (in the middle of the codecademy course) 
- basics of Watir and Mechanize

What I need: 
- a software (IDE) for writing and running scripts for web-automation so I can see results of passed/failed test cases.

I've already tried RubyMine but looking for other alternatives (better if there are tutorials online). 
Thanks in advance and happy Friday! 
Tatyana

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). This is from JetBrains, a very well known company. To start up with selenium you can start with [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for recording and exporting the test then put them on RubyMine and take it from there. [Here](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/6-export-from-selenium-ide) is a step by step instruction how to export the Selenium Tests to different language using IDE

Comment: Thanks, Saifur! Do you personally use RubyMine?

Comment: Not really. I am a C# person. Don't use Ruby. I used a multiple tools from JetBrains and all of them were/are pretty smart and I do not have any complain. That's the reason I directed you to JetBrains as well They are very professional.

Comment: @Tatyana Just though [this](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/intellij/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Selenium+%28The+Official+Selenium+Blog%29) post may help you as well

Comment: I'm a long time vim/vi user, and use it most of the time for developing in most languages; however, when it comes to Ruby, I use RubyMine as well. As for web-automation testing, you should also check out [Ghost Inspector](http://ghostinspector.com) - web based web automation testing, and you can fire the tests remotely via HTTP (there's an [API](https://ghostinspector.com/api/) with methods to execute tests)

Comment: Thank you, @mansilladev ! Will definitely check Ghost Inspector.